# Return char[] from C++/CLR to C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have 2 projects in one solution in Visual Studio, one in C++ talking to some hardware, one in C#, building a GUI and such.

In my .cpp I have some functions that work:

```
namespace ISCOPumpLibrary {
    char data[512];

    bool ISCOPump::Connect(char unit, int com, long baud) {
        commport = com;
        speed = baud;
        unitnum = unit;

        connected = commOpen(commport, speed);
        return connected;
    }

    bool ISCOPump::GetInfo() {
        char in[512], out[512];

        in[0] = 'G';

        Execute(in, out);
        strcpy_s(data, out);

        return true;
    }
```

With a .h file like:

```
namespace ISCOPumpLibrary {
    public ref class ISCOPump
    {
    public:

        static bool Connect(char unit, int com, long baud);
        static bool GetInfo();
```

These are called in the C# program as follows:

```
private void Button_GetInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    bool connected = ISCOPumpLibrary.ISCOPump.Connect(7, 7, 19200);
    bool info = ISCOPumpLibrary.ISCOPump.GetInfo();

    //label_serial.Text += "\r\n" + info;
}
```

This all seems to work. The problem I'm having is I cannot seem to find a way that actually works to return the `char data[512]` or `char out[512]`

I've looked through a bunch of answers but can't find one that looks similar to my case, most seem to be calling these things a little differently.

I've tried using `std::string` or having an argument of `char*`, and haven't had any luck getting C# to like either of those.

Any ideas on how I should get this to work?

**Solution**
*header:*

```
namespace ISCOPumpLibrary {

    using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
    using namespace System;

    public ref class ISCOPump
    {
    public:
        // ISCO Implemented functions.

        //returns success bool
        static bool Connect(char unit, int com, long baud);

        //returns string of info
        static bool GetInfo([Out]String^ %c);
```

*cpp:*

```
namespace ISCOPumpLibrary {
    bool ISCOPump::Connect(char unit, int com, long baud) {
        commport = com;
        speed = baud;
        unitnum = unit;

        connected = commOpen(commport, speed);
        return connected;
    }

    bool ISCOPump::GetInfo([Out]String^ %c) {
        char in[512], out[512];

        in[0] = 'G';

        Execute(in, out);

        c = gcnew String(out);

        return true;
    }
```

*cs:*

```
    private void Button_Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool connected = ISCOPumpLibrary.ISCOPump.Connect(7, 7, 19200);

        ISCOPumpLibrary.ISCOPump.GetInfo(out string data);

        label_serial.Text += "\r\n" + data;
    }
```

Note one of the key details was that the using namespace system calls in the header had to be within the class to prevent all sorts of conflicts.

Comment: Have you looked up P/Invoke?  That's the mechanism you use to call exported C functions (or static C++ functions without mangled names) and to marshal their parameters back and forth.  This site: http://pinvoke.net can be useful to understand how to do this with Windows calls.  You will need to create a what is essentially a function prototype annotated with a DllImport attribute to describe what you want to call.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were using C++/CLR.  Can you not just use a System.String (or System.Text.StringBuilder) in your C++ code?  That would be the easiest way.  I haven't looked at C++/CLR is a _really_ long time.